# Getting the list of installed apps on android

Tags: java, android, gradle

No matter what I do, I am not getting the list of installed apps at all. All I am getting is the list of system apps, and sometimes the app itself which is only the non system app I am getting.

```
    public static List<AppInfo> getInstalledApps(Context context) {
        List<AppInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> apps;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
        } else {
            apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        }

        for (ResolveInfo appInfo : apps) {
            AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
            app.setAppName(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
            app.setPackageName(appInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            app.setIcon(appInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
            installedApps.add(app);
        }

        return installedApps;
    }
```

I want all the user-installed apps. 1 strange thing that the same code is a different app works fine!

```
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded") List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

This works okay in a different app.
Both apps has the

```
    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ReservedSystemPermission" />
```

Permission decleared in their menifest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found whats wrong. Along with the QUERY ALL PACKS permission one must add queries to the menifest.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```